# ArrayList is empty after creating new objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to create an ArrayList of dummy objects using a for loop in my MainActivity.java. This seems to work fine as I get object references for each object I create:

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
  new TaskObjects("Title " + i, "Category " + i, "Description " + i, i + 10);
  Log.d("For Loop", "" + i);
}
```

I have a log(this.toString()) inside the constructor which returns 10 times like this:

D/ARRAY: com.mail.app_appname.TaskObjects@af4fd26 (Each ID different)

TaskObjects class:

```
public class TaskObjects {
  private String title;
  private String category;
  private String description;
  private int taskPosterID;
  private ArrayList<TaskObjects> tasksArray = new ArrayList<>();

  public TaskObjects(String title, String category, String description, int taskPosterID){
    this.title = title;
    this.category = category;
    this.description = description;
    this.taskPosterID = taskPosterID;
    tasksArray.add(this);
    Log.d("ARRAY",this.toString());
  }
  //getters and setters
}
```

However when I try to return the size of the array, it returns 0.

Comment: `I try to return the size of the array, it returns 0.` where ?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to make the `tasksArray` static?

Comment: Basically anywhere I instantiate the class and run object.getTasks().size()

Comment: you are creating a new array with every object so the size would always be 1. But you are not storing the new objects anywhere

Comment: use an external List to store the objects. not inside the objects themselves.

Comment: Note that your `tasksArray` is an instance variable of `TaskObjects`, and in the code being shown, you are initializing a number of `TaskObjects` instances in a loop without even using a reference variable. Bottomline: all `TaskObjects` instances are eligible for garbage collection outside your `for` loop, and any given `TaskObjects` instance will always ever yield *one* element in their `tasksArray` given the present code.

Comment: Allright, I'll add the objects to an array outside the constructor class then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TaskObjects {
  private String title;
  private String category;
  private String description;
  private int taskPosterID;


  public TaskObjects(String title, String category, String description, int taskPosterID){
    this.title = title;
    this.category = category;
    this.description = description;
    this.taskPosterID = taskPosterID;


  }
  //getters and setters
}
```

## MainActivity.java

```
private ArrayList<TaskObjects> tasksArray = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
TaskObjects task=  new TaskObjects("Title " + i, "Category " + i, "Description " + i, i + 10);
tasksArray.add(task);
  Log.d("For Loop", "" + i);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the `tasksArray` static. Otherwise every instance of `TaskObjects` create a new (=empty) `taskArray`

```
private static ArrayList<TaskObjects> tasksArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: yes it works, but it is not a good idea. better storing the instances in an external list.

Comment: depends on what you want to do. see compositum design pattern for example

Comment: I would still use a non-static list for that. in the composite pattern every child node is specific to its parent. so the instances need a list each. that said, there might be situations where a static list is needed. not in OP's question though.